After updating to hibernate 6.2.x and more jsonb doesn't work
I have java class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Content {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "updated", nullable = false)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updated;

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "payload")`your text`
    private Object payload;
}

In post request I can get
@Data
public class MessageRequest {
    @NotNull
    private Content.Type type;
    private String messageText;
    private UUID fileId;
    private Object payload;
}

Where I need to save payload to table. In table content field payload has type jsonb.
When I use hibernate 6.1.x it works, but when I try use hibernate 6.2.x or higher, I get an exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.LinkedHashMap and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.toString(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JsonJdbcType.toString(JsonJdbcType.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.access$000(AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType$1.doBind(AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.lambda$beforeStatement$0(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.spi.BindingGroup.forEachBinding(BindingGroup.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.beforeStatement(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.performInsert(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.execute(MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:816) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:764) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:517) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:439) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:482) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:774) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy181.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:319) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy181.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:618) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:629) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy189.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at asia.dazzlink.chat.service.impl.DialogServiceImpl.sendMessage(DialogServiceImpl.java:142) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at asia.dazzlink.chat.service.impl.DialogServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.sendMessage(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at asia.dazzlink.chat.controller.ChatController.sendMessage(ChatController.java:52) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:261) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at asia.dazzlink.chat.config.LoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(LoggingFilter.java:39) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

I tried to find something useful in google, but couldn't, unfortunately. I tried to use ColumnTransformer, and tried to use columnDefinition, but it didn't work. Please, help.
UPD
I changed Object to JsonNode and it works))

Try running mvn dependency:tree at command line. Perhaps there's a transitive dependency conflict.
